# A building with three floors and three lights

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, story

You wake up in a dim candle lit room. Upon further examination you discover a set of 3 light switches with a note next to them. The note reads:

> Above you are three floors. Each floor contains a light bulb corresponding to a light switch on the wall I front of you. In order to escape you will need to figure out which light switch  corresponds to which floor. You may exit this room to visit the other rooms, but you may not enter this room again. On the back of this note you will find a drawing of the building you are currently in.

[image: Diagram of building]

**How do you figure out which light switch corresponds to which floor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You

> Turn one light on let it heat up, switch it off and turn another light on.  You now have 1 light that is hot, one that is on and one that is off and cold and you know what switches they correspond to.